# how to build a hash-set with an element or without it (depending on condition)?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying this:

```
(hash-set (when (= a 1) x))
```

I'm expecting `#{x}` if `a` equals to `1` and an empty set `#{}` otherwise. But I'm getting `#{nil}` instead of any empty set. How to re-write the statement?

ps. A workaround, but it looks ugly:

```
(filter #(not (nil? %)) (hash-set (when (= a 1) x)))
```

The solution:

```
(apply hash-set (when (= a 1) (list x)))
```

Comment: Just FYI, `(filter #(not (nil? %)) ...)` can usually be rewritten as `(filter identity ...)` - though it falls over if you have boolean false in the collection being filtered. It's slightly more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
(apply hash-set (when (= a 1) x))
```

I'm assuming that a and x are variables, for example via:

```
(defn foo [a & x] (apply hash-set (when (= a 1) x)))
```

I made the parameter x optional since you don't need to provide it if a not equals 1.

Comment: I believe you are needing x to be in a list as the function destructuring does, so `(apply hash-set (when (= a 1) '(x)))`, or I like `(into #{} (when (= a 1) '(x)))`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
(into #{} (when (= a 1) [x]))
```

If you like the word `hash-set` in your code, you can do:

```
(apply hash-set (when (= a 1) [x]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
(if (= a 1) #{x} #{})
```

Comment: You have to remove the last `)`

Comment: The main defect here is the duplication of `#{`. I would like to keep `hash-set` in one place only, for consistency